# Jquery loading Googlemaps onclick in a fadein div

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps, onclick, jquery-animate

I am loading googlemaps on a div on click and it works fine, until I wrap the whole thing in a container with opacity 0 and add an animate opacity to it, then the map onclick stops working.

I realise it's not about the jquery, but once I wrap the divs into container div in the html, that's when it stops working.

Can anyone help?

Here's the html

```
<div id="container">
<div id="left"><p>show map</p></div>
<div id="Grid">
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

This is the bit of jquery :

```
$("#container").delay(1000).animate({
    opacity: 1

}, 2000);
```

And here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Alga/Mcjg5/10/

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not jQuery, its the css
If you add:

```
#map-canvas {
height: 100px;
}
```

it works fine. The height was 0px so you didn't saw the maps

here an jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Alga/Mcjg5/10/